# Hmm, IO::Async can't even handle 10k connections?

Tags: linux, perl, networking, io-async

Hi I built a very simple HTTP server and only to do a stress testing on POE module.

Here's how I tested it:

```
for x in {1..10000}; do
  curl xxxxx:12342 --retry-delay 5 --retry 3 -d randombytes$x 
done
```

When I do that I see multiple "Connection Reset" by peer message, so for this 10k connection I lost about 1200 requests in total.

Is there anyway to improve its performance? Tested nginx on the same server, no kernel parameters was changed during that, no connection reset message at all.

**EDIT**

I already increased max fileno / per user max fileno, the former was `fs.file-max = 3246455`, and the latter was `10240`

Attached source code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Net::Async::HTTP::Server;
use IO::Async::Loop;

use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Response;
use Data::Dumper;

my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new();

my $httpserver = Net::Async::HTTP::Server->new(
    on_request => sub {
        my ($self, $req) = @_;
        my ($code, $result) = (200, "It works\n");

        my $response = HTTP::Response->new ($code);
        $response->add_content ($result);
        $response->content_type ("application/json");
        $response->content_length (length $response->content);

        $req->respond($response);
    },
);

$loop->add( $httpserver );

$httpserver->listen(
    addr => { family => "inet", socktype => "stream", port => 8080 },
    on_listen_error => sub { die "Cannot listen - $_[-1]\n" },
);

say 'Listening normally on ', 8080;

$loop->run;
```

Comment: Tags say POE, description and code say IO::Async. I'll retag

Comment: @LeoNerd hmm I just didn't find the io::async tag, thanks

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably find you're coming up on the "file descriptors per process" limit. By default that's 1024.

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
```

If you want to handle 10,000 concurrent connections then obviously you'll need at least one file descriptor per connection. Accounting for a few extra for the process and some extra headroom for stale ones, you probably want to set this to about 11k.

Only root can increase the FD limit:

```
$ sudo -s
Password:
# ulimit -n 11000
# ulimit -n
11000
```

At this point you can now run your server. (Don't forget to switch back to the UID required, so as not to run it as root).

When running such a large number of connections via `IO::Async` you'll probably want to use something better than the default built-in `poll` or `select`-based Loops. For example on Linux you likely want to install the `epoll` loop, as well as the `linux` one so it will automatically load.

```
$ cpan IO::Async::Loop::Epoll
$ cpan IO::Async::Loop::linux
```

Comment: ulimit shows 10240 (which is adjusted prior to this stress testing), I increased it to 65535 anyway

Comment: Also, how can I know if these two modules are "selected"? I have them installed

Comment: my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new; say ref($loop)    # Will print the kind of loop you actually have

Comment: As to knowing how many spare FDs are left, I'm not sure offhand. I suspect that's a topic for a new SO question.

Comment: Is there a "backlog" option in IO::Async?

Comment: Resolved. It was the `queuesize` in the listen method.

Comment: @warl0ck, Please write that up as an answer.